# How should I deal with an ajax get function, that is reused across multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a web application with booking/reservation-functionality. One of my core functions is to check whether a booking conflicts with other bookings, and this function is used across multiple pages. Its return data is not usually loaded with a page, as it's request parameters are dependent upon user input. In other words:

- I have an ajax function, that gets booking data
- It is abstracted away into it's own .js file, for reusability
- The ajax function is wrapped in a javascript function.

However, an ajax function is not suitable for my intended use. The wrapper function will return nothing, before the ajax call is complete, due to it's asynchronous nature. If i need to execute something with the returned data, it should be inside the success-function of the ajax call, but as I need different things to happen, based on in which page, and which situation the data is needed.

I see three solutions to my problem. I just can't decide which is the best approach, or if there might be a fourth and better option:

**1. Skip the abstraction of the ajax function.** In other words, just copy/paste it into every function where I need the data, and voilla; I would have the success-condition function available at all times.

**2. Pass a succes-function as a parameter.** If i need something dynamic to happen, I could make it so, by passing a function to the ajax-wrapper function, and making sure that the passed function accepts the ajax returned data as it's own parameter.

**3. Make the ajax call synchronous.** Possible, but kind of ruins the concept of **a**jax (actually I am also using JSON, so that will make ajax into sjoj).

Honestly, I really can't see that either of the solutions stand out as the winner here. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using an event based approach.
Inside ajax success you can fire (trigger) an event for example `booking-check-complete` and the specific page handles the event the way it needs.

This way you keep the benefits of the ajax being well - **asynchronous** and keep the pages **decoupled**.

For uses like this I use jQuery event mechanism, but there are also other libraries available. Check it out here - [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

**For example in page one you have:**

```
$( document ).on( "booking-check-complete", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( "Hello from page 1" );
});
```

**On the second page you have:**

```
$( document ).on( "booking-check-complete", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( "Hello from page 2" );
});
```

**And in ajax success:**

```
$( document ).trigger( "booking-check-complete", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```

**NOTE**
You don't need jQuery to use events as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)
This uses plain javascript, but it is not compatible with IE.

```
var event = new Event('build');

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) { ... }, false);

// Dispatch the event.
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Nice! I am at least medium proficient in jquery, so that will work nicely. I suppose I could use a variable to pass a specific trigger to the jquery function as well, making it completely dynamic.

This stands out as the winning answer to me, but I want to make sure that I can make it work, before greening it :).

Comment: Yes, you can pass parameters to the event. In the example param1 will be the string "Custom" and param2 will be "Event". If you don't use jQuery in your project you may consider adding a more light weight library that does the same without the overhead of functionality you may not need. Cheers!

Comment: I do use jquery extensivly ;). And we have a winner! I have made it work. The bookings are returned correctly, and the event is triggered. Now I just need to iterate over them, and display them correctly. Thank you good sir, You have been most helpful! I have made progress as a developer today!

Comment: ...and when I was talking about variables earlier, I meant `var event_to_trigger = "booking-check-complete"`, and then calling `$( document ).on( event_to_trigger, function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( "Hello from page 1" );
});`. This also works ;)

Comment: Glad to hear that! Events are a powerful tool. I have dedicated a common js structure across the site with constants like that in it and call Events.BookingComplete for example instead of "booking-check-complete". This way I know that all the declared events are in one place.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. That violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
2. Yes. This is idiomatic JavaScript.
3. No. That locks up the UI (and synchronous XHR is deprecated).

Option 2  is the standout winner.

Comment: Great, specific and short answer. The one with events also seems very promising. I need to test the options now :)